# Delete Cascade on Code First - One-to–Zero-or-One

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have an Entity named **Items**, then I have several entities that have a foreign key **(NOT NULLABLE)** to this table key **ItemId**.

Then I have another table named **Soldiers** that depends also on **Items**, but in this case it's a **(NULLABLE)** foreign key.

When I delete an item on the **Items** table I get an error regarding items that exist on the **Soldiers** table. If I don't have **Soldiers** with items I don't get the error, and all the other tables are correctly cascade deleted.

I guess I have to put something on the Fluent API to cascade delete also on this table, but I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it with [**`WithCascadeOnDelete`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696319%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
   .HasMany(i => i.Soldiers)
   .WithOptional(s => s.Item)
   .HasForeignKey(s => s.ItemId)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Soldier>()
   .HasOptional(s => s.Item)
   .WithMany() // -> use i => i.Soldiers if any
   .HasForeignKey(i => i.ItemId)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I cannot see the Soldiers property on the ``i => i.``.

Comment: @ChristopherBailey, you can add `public virtual ICollection<Soldier> Soldiers {get;set;}` on `Item`, I also provide another option to configure it from `Soldier`

Comment: It does not work :( I get the following when I run the ``update-database`` 
``Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Soldiers_dbo.Items_ItemId' on table 'Soldiers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint.``

Comment: @ChristopherBailey, could you post your classes and configuration ?

Comment: I found that I had another cascade path that might be delete the same table data. It's now ok. Thanks for your help. +1